# Create a HTML table from a xml document in ASP.NET/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am querying a web service and get returned a SOAP message. I want to create a html table and select what node should be in what column and so on. I have been googling a bit but wonder if anyone of you know a good guide on how to do this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way would be a XSL Transformation (XSLT). [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) for a good tutorial on XSLT.

Comment: The xml is returned in a string so can't I create the table on the server side?

Comment: @Peter: You can compile XSLT on server site with System.Xml.Xsl namespace classes. Also you can parse the XML string with System.Xml.Linq (XLinq) objects or System.Xml (XmlDocument, etc.) objects.

Comment: Yes, with XSLT. .NET has build-in classes for these transformations, you only need to write the appropriate XSLT file!

Comment: soo any examples on how to do this?

Comment: You really should have a look at the example from w3schools. They provide an online transformation tool where you can see how it works: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: yeah I saw that but I don't know how to implement it in C#. Thanks for the links anyway.

Comment: Just follow this simple example, you'll see how easy this is with the help of the .NET framework :) http://www.15seconds.com/issue/060608.htm